# "Adjacent" is to "adjacency" as "contains" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

An *adjacency* relation is one which denotes whether two objects are *adjacent*.

> The two neighbors are adjacent, and hence have an adjacency relation.

What is the equivalent for a "contains" relation, for example:

> The box contains oranges, and hence they have a *???* relationship.

I am not sure whether *"containment"* is appropriate given its connotations.

Note that the word may not necessarily be based on *"contains"*, perhaps on a synonym.

Comment: The word 'containment' is probably most commonly encountered in the political/military domain. In fact, Collins doesn't give the more transparent definition (The act or condition of containing _ AHD & RHK Webster's). However, that definition is valid, and  even appears in the compound 'containment metaphors' See [container metaphors](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsAContainerMetaphor.htm)

Comment: There seems to be no such noun derivative of the verb *contain*. We may have to select a synonym of *contain* and use its derivative instead.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Although the first (natural) definition of *containment* happens to be "n. 1. The act or condition of containing," today it is not much used in that sense. The word has acquired specialized meanings in the domains of politics and science. So it is: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/containment?q=containment

Comment: @Kris I have already said much the same. That doesn't make the natural sense, given by quality dictionaries, incorrect/unusable. In fact, I'd say that in 'containment metaphor' exactly that sense is being used.

Comment: Containment in that sense is not a passive or static relationship though, it's a purposeful restriction of growth.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How about 'continence'? Or is that too much associated with one particular form of containment?

Comment: @Neil Act **or condition**.

Comment: @WS2 Have you a dictionary reference licensing that sense? I've not found one.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  OED's etymology of the adjective 'continent' follows. Note how the final ref is to the verb 'contain'.  < Old French continent 12th cent. in Littré, in sense 1), < Latin continēnt-em lit. ‘holding together’, hence ‘contiguous, connected, continuous’, also ‘holding oneself in, self-restraining, restraining one's passions’ (the latter the sense in which the word was first taken into the modern languages), present participle of continēre : see contain v.

Comment: @WS2 But this doesn't license modern usage in the spatial sense of containment.

Comment: Is this a test type question, I mean is there a definite answer? I ask only out of interest as it seems to have stumped the EL&U experts.

Comment: One problem is that *adjacent* is an adjective (which requires a preposition, *adjacent to*) and *contains* is a verb. And I'm not convinced about *adjacency* -- that smacks of *normalcy* to me.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Go on - have a stab at it, go on, go on, go on, go on. I'm sure this **is** a textbook question and must have an answer. I thought there might be some sort of inanimate version of _symbiotic_ but I couldn't find it, but I'm sure it'll be something like that.

Comment: @Neil: "Containment in that sense is not a passive or static relationship though, it's a purposeful restriction of growth." So is what a bottle does.  The growing puddle under a leaky bottle is proof enough of that.

Comment: Try to find a sentence that would use the word (and isn't totally contrived like the one you have given), and you'll realise why there isn't a suitable word.

Adjacent isn't even equivalent to 'contains', which is more like 'adjacent to'.

Comment: The basic analogy is not entirely apt for a reason not yet mentioned.  Adjacency is a transitive predicate: if one thing is adjacent to a second, then the second is adjacent to the first.  This does not hold for the predicate 'contains.'  Hence you are not likely to find a word that 'measures up' neatly to 'adjacency'.  'Encapsulation' is my favorite of the suggestions so far.

Comment: I eventually went with _Enclosure_ for the bounty, because it does satisfy the relationship in both directions : _the act of enclosing or state of being enclosed_.

Comment: @Merk: You seem to be confusing transitivity with reflexivity.  Containment is transitive.

Comment: @nomen--quite so...Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 15):

There seems to be some reluctance to sanction the use of 'containment' in a spatial sense.

Mukergee and Sarkar have no such qualms in their article [Grounded Acquisition of Containment Prepositions](http://cse.iitk.ac.in/users/amit/pub/mukerjee-sarkar-icon07_grounded-preposition-acquisition.pdf)
:

> ... Here we demonstrate that it is possible for a purely perceptual
>   system to form notions of containment, well recognised as one of the
>   earliest spatial concepts arising around the age of six months
>   (Casasola et al, 2003)....

And neither do Lockwood et al in [Automatic Classification of Containment and Support Spatial Relations in English and Dutch](http://spatiallearning.org/publications_pdfs/Lockwood12.pdf):

> ... For example, in English containment relationships are categorised
>   as 'in' and support relationships are classified as 'on'....

Comment: Yes, 'containment' is clearly the answer here.  To 'contain' means 'to hold within'.  A container is an object that restricts its contents (i.e., holds them) from becoming non-contents.  The "political" usage is just a simple metaphorical extension (and it's not so metaphorical).

Comment: As a random example of use in the wild, the documentation of Inform7 (a programming language for interactive fiction) uses the word [containment](http://inform7.com/learn/man/doc224.html) when discussing how to model such a relationship.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to answer the question.

First (the serious answer) consider how relationships are named in scholarly discourse in the topic. An [influential paper](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:58578:2/component/escidoc:58579/Levinson_2003_natural.pdf) on topological relationships in natural language semantics includes the following passage:

> Most approaches to spatial language have assumed that the simplest
>   spatial notions are (after Piaget) topological and universal
>   (containment, contiguity, proximity, support, represented as semantic
>   primitives such as IN, ON, UNDER, etc.)

If scholars who discuss containment relationships use the term *containment*, you could hardly be considered silly for doing the same.

Second (the facetious answer). *Adjacent* takes its nominal form from the paradigm for the Latin source word from which it ultimately derives. The present active neuter participle for Latin *adjacere* 'lie beside' is *adjacentia* 'lying beside'. *Contain* ultimately derives from Latin *continere* 'hold together'. Its present active neuter participle is *continentia* 'holding together'. So the word you are looking for is *continence*. But even in Latin *continentia* could refer to self-restraint and chastity. Medical use of the term in English dates to the early 20th century (though *incontinent* is attested in the 18th century).

Comment: If the box has an *incontinent* relationship with the oranges, perhaps it leaks orange juice?

Comment: @Andy very funny.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that the "containment" question can be correlated to adjacency.  Adjacency is a mutual relationship, both parties are adjacent to the other.  The oranges will never contain the box. The box will always be the dominant party in this example, thereby fulfilling the requirement of restricting growth, if you will.  I like "container-contained", but it does sound a little too textbook for conversational use.  The cop-out answer of "There isn't an answer" is looking better and better.

Comment: Absolutely, it's the mutual relationship that's key. The relationship needs to apply to both the box and the oranges. As I mentioned in the comments to the question _symbiotic_ describes it for living things. What's needed is an inanimate version of _symbiotic_ (sort of). Feel free to add another answer if you think of one. I won't be giving out the bounty until it is due.

Comment: I kept coming back to symbiotic as well, but couldn't come up with an inanimate approximation.

Comment: The box contains oranges, and hence they have a coexisting relationship. [?] To exist together, at the same time, or in the same place. They could exist apart but not without breaking the relationship.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics you could say one is a **subset** of the other (in abstract term) or that they have an **inclusion** relationship.

Containment of one item into another is, however, a directional relation as opposed to adjacency. Therefore the xxx relationship may not indicate which is inside which.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get the reluctance to accept *containment*.

Compare [its definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/containment) with that of [adjacency](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adjacency) on Dictionary.com, particularly where they provide the Collins English Dictionary definition.

Containment:

> the act or condition of containing...

Adjacency:

> being near or close...

Both then have an 'especially' clause. For containment, it's the political/military definition that has everyone here thinking twice. For adjacency, it's sharing a common boundary. But we aren't thinking twice about using it to describe the relationship between close objects that do not share a boundary.

I tend to agree that due to the asymmetry of containment and the symmetry of adjacency, as relationships, the semantic analogy is limited. As it happens, I think *containment* mirrors *adjacency* better than *contains* mirrors *adjacent*.

Answer (score 2):

**I'll take another stab at this**. The problem is that the analogy "adjacent is to adjacency as contains is to **______**," is not in parallel form. Adjacent is an adjective but contains is a verb. To be parallel, *contained* should be used, as in: adjacent is to adjacency as contained is to **________**. As adjacency is the quality described by saying that two things are adjacent, a word is needed for the quality described by saying that something is contained. One way to name the quality of something being contained is ***inclusion***.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [container/contained relationship](http://books.google.fr/books?id=NjBj6DT1pFkC&pg=PA103&dq=%22contained+relationship%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=L0uLU_GpK8ub0AW76YDgDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22contained%20relationship%22&f=false).

> The box contains oranges, and hence they have a [container/contained relationship](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28container%2Fcontained+relationship%29%2C%28container-contained+relationship%29%2Ccontainment+relationship&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28container%20/%20contained%20relationship%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28container%20-%20contained%20relationship%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontainment%20relationship%3B%2Cc0).

Alternately, [penetration relationship](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/70193/24882122.pdf?sequence=1) is a concept you might want to consider (See p. 25).

Comment: I think that's what Edwin was getting at but I'm not convinced. It looks like a text book question (it might not be, I did ask for clarification but none was forthcoming) especially with the additional hint of _not necessarily based on contains_. Feel free to add another answer if you can think of one.

Comment: @Frank I continue to think "container/contained relationship" is the best fit here. "Adjacency relation" makes sense only because one is adjacent to another (and vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a ***compositional relationship:***

> [composition:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compositional) *(n) The combining of distinct parts or elements to form a whole.*
>
> *adj: compositional*

The elements {box, oranges} have a *compositional* relationship because when taken together, the box and oranges form *a box of oranges.*

Comment: +1 That might be it. The relationship between both the box and the oranges is _compositional_ because together they make _a box of oranges_. Without one or the other there is no _box of oranges_. That sounds like a good candidate.

Comment: @Frank Yes, exactly. That was my thinking as well. Cheers.

Comment: Whoever down voted this answer please add a comment as to why. It might not be the best answer, but I think it's certainly a good one and providing an explanation as to why it's not would be helpful to both me and the community.

Comment: Well, I downvoted this because it is *completely wrong*.  As other answers have indicated, this simply doesn't map to the sense the OP was asking about.   Normally I only leave a comment if I think an answer can be improved; I simply disagree with this one.  Things can have a compositional relationship without any idea of containment, and things can be in a containment relationship without composing anything.

Comment: @starwed thank you for the reply and reasoned response. It seems that this actually was the relationship the OP was referring to given the OP +1'd it

Comment: Frank was not the OP, though they did add a bounty.

Comment: This was at the top of my list for being the bounty answer until @starwed provided _enclosure_ as it doesn't need the extra thought of _a box of oranges_. For the bounty _contains_ was not a requirement, only a single word that described the two way relationship which I think this does.

Answer (score 1):

I think "containment" is inappropriate, as it implies that the purpose of the relationship is restriction.

I also disagree that this is a "compositional" relationship; the term is too vague. It could describe many relationships between nouns - 'a bunch of flowers', for example - without necessarily implying one thing being within the other.

And conversely, if an oven contains a cake, that should be equivalent to the box of oranges, but it's nonsense to say an "oven of cake". Which is to say you can have one thing within another, and it's not necessarily 'compositional'.

How about "nesting"? See the third meaning of the verb [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nest):

> to form a hierarchy, series, or sequence of with each member, element,
>   or set contained in or containing the next

I like this because it means both 'contained in' and 'containing'.

Comment: But the purpose of a container **is** restriction... It restricts its contents from being non-contents.

Comment: Hi @nomen. Thanks for pointing this out. You're completely right, of course. I disagree with 'containment' only on grounds of personal taste. For me it suggests keeping something harmful under control.

Comment: Nesting? How about _nestling_? The oranges can be _nestling_ inside the box, can the box be described as _nestling_ the oranges?

Comment: Hi @Frank. I don't think one thing can nestle another.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach:

If "are adjacent" is one by the other, "contains" is one within the other. (instead of *within*, *inside* or *in* can be used also)

So the answer is:

> one-within-the-other relationship

---

As an etymological approach, I'm going to say ***encapsulating relationship***. (or encapsulation)

> *[encapsulate:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=encapsulate)* from en- (1) "make, put in" + capsule + -ate
>
> ---
>
> [capsule:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=capsule&allowed_in_frame=0) from Latin capsula "small box or chest," diminutive of capsa "box, case, chest"
>
> ---
>
> [*-ate:*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ate&allowed_in_frame=0) verbal suffix for Latin verbs in -are, identical with -ate (1).

So, the word originally means putting in a box. As the example suggests, we put oranges in a box. There you go!

Comment: (Encapsulatory?) or [Encapsulation](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/encapsulation) relationship, works better? Maybe not...

Comment: Hmm encapsulatory does not seem like a word. But "encapsulating relationship" is used in this sense also. Nice source to back up! :)

Answer (score 1):

The word *enclosure* is the best alternative to *containment* I could find.  From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/enclosure):

> the act of enclosing or state of being enclosed

Comment: That's it. _enclosure_ is the relationship; it's the only one that goes both ways without having to add in any extra stuff. @JasonM was so close but _enclosing_ is only one half. Keshlam noted it in a comment but you can't 'bountificate' a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with *enclosing*, but it isn't really a natural usage.

Comment: It needs to apply to both parties, the box and the oranges, in the same way that the adjacent relationship applies to both neighbours. I'm sure there is an answer because the question sounds like a textbook question. Feel free to add another answer if you can think of one.

Comment: "Enclosure" would be the general relationship composed of "enclosed in" and "enclosed by"

Comment: @keshlam _Enclosure_ is the (my accepted) answer but I can't bounty a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Adjacent is to adjacency as contains is to *package*. Two things side by side are adjacent. Two things, one containing the other form a package. Package can refer at one and the same time to the container and its contents so enclosed. Whereas with adjacency, the relationship of the two objects is beside each other, with containment, the relationship is within and without each other.

The box contains oranges, and hence they have a *packaging* relationship.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more it seems weird to me. Even though a package is an example of the relationship, it is not an adequate name for the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Containerized (see 2nd definition below)

From Merriam-Webster Online:

Main Entry: con·tain·er·ize 
Pronunciation: \kən-ˈtā-nə-ˌrīz, -nər-ˌīz\
Function: verb
Inflected Form(s): con·tain·er·ized; con·tain·er·iz·ing
Date: 1956
transitive verb
1 :  to ship by containerization 2 :  to pack in containers

If the oranges have been packed into a container, then the oranges have been containerized.

Original form: The box contains oranges, and hence they have a [containerized] relationship.

Answer (score 0):

**Container**. An adjacency is something that is adjacent.  A container is something that contains.  *X* is an adjacency of *Y* if it is adjacent to *Y*.  *X* is a container of *Y* if it contains *Y*.

Comment: No doubt that the box is a container of oranges if it contains oranges, but the oranges are not a container of the box. What is asked for is a relationship term that describes both the relationship of the box to the oranges and the oranges to the box in the same X is adjacent to Y means that Y is adjacent to X. Now I've written that it's only just dawned on me that if the oranges were outside the box then their relationship would be 'adjacent' so maybe it's a word like 'adjacent' we're looking for.

Comment: @Frank Of course that is the case. Adjacency is **commutative**. Containment is **not** (in general).  The OP chose the relation, not I.

Comment: Indeed but the OP also offered this _Note that the word may not necessarily be based on "contains", perhaps on a synonym._ which is why I'm not wholly convinced any amount of bending _contain_ into such a relationship will ever be correct.

Comment: @Frank: Any **synonym** of contains will also need to be not (necessarily) commutative. It's in the nature of the **relation**, regardless of what name you call it.

Comment: Then perhaps you could have a go at second part of the bounty information by providing a _half-decent reason_ for _No, there isn't one [a word for the relationship that is]_ because so far your reasoning is the closest to explaining why there isn't (and possibly can't be) a single word for the relationship.

Comment: @Frank The word for the relationship is **containment** -- or as a noun, *contains*. I gave a word for the thing that does the containing: **container**. *X* is a *container* of *Y* if *X* contains Y. The relation is not a commutative relation; that's all. If the OP wants a different word for *container* then s?he can choose a synonym for *container*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with finding a term to describe what the OP calls ‘*a "contains" relation*’ is a reflection of the fact that in many situations, English speakers don’t seem to have felt the need to devise abstract categorizations of this sort; or if they have, they are often restricted to particular domains, such as mathematics.

To take one notable example, there doesn’t even seem to be a *general* abstract term to describe the relationship between siblings, at least in dictionaries: the metadictionary Onelook.com returns no hits for plausible terms like *siblingdom, siblingry* or *siblingship*. When the need for a similar term does arise, it is usually spelled out in specifics:  *brother-sister relationship, sister-sister relationship*.

I think one of the reasons for the lack of a general term for a *container-contained object relationship* is that in everyday situations it is rarely necessary to describe such a relationship in abstract terms. Usually, the context requires a much more explicit description:

> “Please replace the cutlery in the drawer after use”
>
> “The cat is in the box again!”
>
> “The hold of the ferry accommodates up to 25 buses or 45 passenger cars”.

The lack of mutuality between the containing object and the object contained presents a further difficulty when one attempts to encapsulate the relationship using a single term. The best I can come up with is *inclusion relationship* (the same suggestion as that proposed by **GMB** and **hauron**).

Answer (score -2):

A 'bulk' relationship: *The box contains oranges, and hence they have a* [**bulked**](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/175964/bulked) *relationship.*

**Break Bulk** : To unload and distribute a portion or all of the contents of a rail car, **container**, or trailer. - Loose, non-containerized cargo. -Glossary of shipping terms (U.S. Dept. of Transportation, Maritime Administration, [1999])